# PS4 slim won't recognize controller

Tags: ps4, controllers

I'm at my wit's end please help me. I have done all the things I needed to do with the controller and it still won't pick up. It does charge it but won't let me do anything with the PS4 even when I put it in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try resetting the controller?

- Find a paperclip and press the reset button (under L2)
- Hold it for ten seconds
- Then press and hold the PS button

If that doesn't work try this:
http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/bluetooth.html